# Generating object which props are a subset of the props of another object based on array in Typescript

Tags: typescript, generics, type-inference

The title I wrote might be a bit convoluted, so I'll try to explain what I'm trying to do below.

Let's say I have the following type for a document:

```
type Doc<TData extends {}> = {
  data: TData;
}
```

And also the following function where I can pass the document and an array of the properties in data:

```
declare function setData<TDoc extends Doc<{}>>(document: TDoc, keys: Array<keyof TDoc["data"]>): void;
```

Now, let's say I create the following types and const based on them:

```
type PersonData = {
  name: string;
  address: string;
  age: number;
  nickname: string;
  zipCode: string;
}

type PersonDoc = Doc<PersonData>;

declare const person: PersonDoc;
```

If I call my `setData` function with the person object, the second parameter (`keys`) will be an array of the properties in data, in this case:

```
Array<"name" | "address" | "age" | "nickname" | "zipCode">
```

Which means I can call the function like:

```
setData(person, ["name", "age"]);
```

Doing that will tell typescript to enforce that argument to be an array of those props.

Now, here's what I want to do, which I have been trying unsuccessfully the whole day and I think I might be trying to push typescript a bit too far.

Let's say I add a third argument to the `setData` function, I need that third argument to be an object with the properties I set in the `keys` argument, but with each property being one specific type.

Something like this (which doesn't work):

```
type Definition = {
    type: string;
    isKey: boolean;
}

type OtherObject<T extends Array<string>> = {
    [K in T[number]]: Definition;
}

declare function setData<TDoc extends Doc<{}>>(document: TDoc, keys: Array<keyof TDoc["data"]>, otherObject: OtherObject</* keys argument */>): void;
```

Which would mean that, if I called the `setData` function this time, the third argument `otherObject` would have to be of the following type:

```
{
  name: Definition;
  address: Definition;
}
```

So, this is what it would look like:

```
setData(person, ["name", "age"], {
  name: {
    type: "something",
    isKey: false
  },
  age: {
    type: "something2"
    isKey: false
  }
});
```

And, of course, if I missed either `name` or `age` in the object, typescript would give me an error.

So, this is what I'm trying to achieve. I don't mind if instead of a function it's an object type instead, like:

```
type Options<TDoc extends Doc<{}>> = {
     keys: Array<keyof TDoc["data"]>;
     otherObject: OtherObject</* keys argument */>;
}
```

For my purposes, I could go either way. I have been trying this the whole day without success, I've done many google searches and nothing.

I think I might be trying to push typescript a bit too far, so asking on StackOverflow is my last resort before I completely give up.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Could you knock up a playground, https://www.typescriptlang.org/play it makes it much easier for others to help, and more likely to get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work by changing the following definitions (and OtherObject is no longer required):

```js
declare function setData<TData extends {}, K extends keyof TData>(
  document: Doc<TData>,
  keys: Array<K>,
  modifiedValues: Record<K, Definition>
): void;
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=22&ssc=147&pln=22&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCIHsEB4Aqq5hzIQAekIAJgM7IDeAvgHx0BQyyFBcAXMnlwG4W9Fi1CRYiFAAVoVdCHyFW7EHAC2EXlTBRQAcyHs4FClAhUq23QaPI4+rchABXdQCNodkMAQBrNU1rPRBDNmQAL2AABwBhdAonHRCwkRYwAE9omTkFDARkAF40TCxZKHlFLkYhFkSEABs4c2QEBR1kbIqFXnLK-NrxaHgkNAgYUGAwYAUVdmRM7ODbcPZgKgBpCAzed3R0Bog4ECE0+qaWmBcQBGnZqggwJThcZ+IyCEoaBgAaZA33uRqMg-Nt0DA+M9GAAKCiYNyfMC8fKvap-UEZKzIACCUCgcAyWA2jD+6DAAAtoAB5dwAKwgt14ACUGegoBQiX9UONJncQIwAJS8ABu6GAFFqDyeXGhXUqfwA2gAiQIQJV-JUONUAXT+tHCqt4+vmCyyTiV8k0FIM6tWyHWWx2yHgDQe4XoP3CWqNdsW5stj3JBgATLaTQ7trwXW72CJ6AKBEA)

It probably can be improved.